# The type of the value being assigned to variable "User::de_sters" differs from the current variable type

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a variable `de_sters`, a string type variable, as it is defined in my SSIS package, its scope is SSIS package, which I need to `fill` with the value of several lines from one table, usig an `Execute Sql Task` package.

Bottom line is that I have an "Execute Sql Task" package, in proprieties ->"Sql Statement" I have wrote:

```
declare @s varchar(max) = '' 
select @s =  case when @s <> '' 
                  then  @s + ',''' + employer_name + '''' 
                  else   @s + '''' + employer_name+ ''''
                  end 
from employers
select @s as Result
```

Then, at `Result Set` I selected `Single Row` (first I have ran my select and I saw that it returns only one line). Then on tab `Result Set` (left side) I  wrote in `Result Name` field `Result` (the alias from my previous sql statement) and in filed `Variable Name` I wrote `User::de_sters`.

But when I run sql task it gives me

```
The type of the value being assigned to variable "User::de_sters"
differs from the current variable type" error.
```

Any help, or hints?

Comment: @praveen: Hello, the hole statement returns: 'john','doe','smith' instead of (line1) john (line2) doe  (line3) smith.  For my package, I need to have the exact string 'john','doe','smith' loaded in variable "de_sters", as it helps me later on to delete something on a different data base. Therefore if ran the hole statement will return only 'john','doe','smith'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is SSIS doesn't understand `varchar(max)` as a data type .You need to specify the `limit` .Just change `max` value to `8000` .

```
declare @s varchar(8000) = ''
```

If your  string  is very large then use FullResultSet with `varchar(max)` in your query and store the value in a variable whose data type is  `object`.

Now in order to access the object use `Script task` or `Script component` (Data Flow) and write the below code to extract the value from the `object` variable

```
OleDbDataAdapter oleDA = new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
oleDA.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::YourVariable"].Value);
 foreach (DataRow rowLoop in dt.Rows)
     {
        MessageBox.Show (rowLoop[0].ToString());
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

To load a `varchar(max)` field within `SQL Script Tasks` in `Control flow` to a string variable, you should split it to smaller chunks eg. `varchar(4000)` and load them to an `object`, and within the next step add a `foreach loop container` to combine them back to a `string` variable,

to split a large text to smaller texts as rows you can use the following Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SSIS_VarcharMax_Loader 
     @Input varchar(max) ,
     @maxRowLength int = 50
 AS
 BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON


 ;WITH 
     tmp(inp,c,rn) as (
              select @Input,SUBSTRING(@Input, 1,@maxRowLength),@maxRowLength
           union all
              select @Input,SUBSTRING(@Input,rn,@maxRowLength),rn + @maxRowLength
              from tmp
              where rn < len(@Input)
        )
      select c from tmp
      OPTION (MAXRECURSION 500);

 END;
```

then add the following expression in an expression task contained by a foreach container over the rows and concat them back to one string,

```
@strResult = (ISNULL(@[User::strResult])?"": @[User::strResult] )+  @[User::str]
```

[image: asd]
[image: asd]
[image: asd]
[image: asd]
[image: asd]